# How to align an image in the same line of two paragraphs?

Tags: css, flexbox, display

I have the folowing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Temporal veraniego</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/testing7style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Un importante temporal
    </h1>
    <section>
    <p>Hoy hubo un temporal importante en la Ciudad de Buenos Aires y provincia. En lo personal estoy sin internet, por suerte con luz. Espero a pesar de la lluvia ver a mi amigo hoy, que me visita; vamos a compartir un café. No sé bien a dónde iremos, pues la inflación está haciendo estragos en el país, las pensiones, las jubilaciones, los salarios no crecen como deberían.</p>
    <p>En Buenos Aires la historia del verano es casi siempre la misma. Mucha humedad, mucho calor; luego una gran tormmenta. Parece las crisis cíclicas del capitalismo. Es triste, porque muchos sufren estas crisis y otros están preparados para sacar una buena tajada. En este momemento estoy leyendo "La Era del Capital, 1848-1875" de Eric Hobsbawm, justamente narra un poco esta cuestión. Puedo decir que es un libro muy recomendable, se lee fácil. Considero que Eric era un gran hombre, además de un gran historiador. Él se oponía a una sociedad meritocrática. Es una pena, realmente que ya no lo tengamos entre nosotros.</p>
    </section>
    <img src="imgs/smartOwl.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

And the code of the css file would be:

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
body{
    background-color: ;
}
img{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem that I trying to solve is that I need the image to be display to the right of the paragraphs, in the same line. I don't know how to achive that. I tried inline, inline-block, block; wouldn't work. Hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Move all the paragraphs into one div and use the flexbox in the section to fulfill your requirement.

```css
h1 {
   text-align: center;
}

body {
   background-color: ;
}

img {
   width: 25%;
   height: 25%;
   display: inline-block;
}

p {
   margin-top: 0;
}

section {
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Un importante temporal
    </h1>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>Hoy hubo un temporal importante en la Ciudad de Buenos Aires y provincia. En lo personal estoy sin internet, por suerte con luz. Espero a pesar de la lluvia ver a mi amigo hoy, que me visita; vamos a compartir un café. No sé bien a dónde iremos, pues la inflación está haciendo estragos en el país, las pensiones, las jubilaciones, los salarios no crecen como deberían.</p>
            <p>En Buenos Aires la historia del verano es casi siempre la misma. Mucha humedad, mucho calor; luego una gran tormmenta. Parece las crisis cíclicas del capitalismo. Es triste, porque muchos sufren estas crisis y otros están preparados para sacar una buena tajada. En este momemento estoy leyendo "La Era del Capital, 1848-1875" de Eric Hobsbawm, justamente narra un poco esta cuestión. Puedo decir que es un libro muy recomendable, se lee fácil. Considero que Eric era un gran hombre, además de un gran historiador. Él se oponía a una sociedad meritocrática. Es una pena, realmente que ya no lo tengamos entre nosotros.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </section>
</body>
```

After using the flex you can move your image to the different position like top, center and end as per the requirement.

Comment: Prashant. Do you know if I can add an image here in the code?

Comment: Currently, I have added the dummy image to check your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prashant. Now, I have other question. How can I change the size of the image? I'm trying and failing. I switched the img display to inline-block, inline and block and still can not change the size.